# std::Function instance creation

Tags: c++, c++11

Hi all i'm trying to create an instance of a Class using this following setup:

```
class Interface
{
      Interface(){}
      virtual void init =0;
};

class InstanceCreation
{

void registerInstance(const std::string& name, std::function<Interface*(void)> interface )
{
functionMap[name] = interface 
}


Interface* getInstance(const std::string& name)
{
 Interface* temp;
 auto itor = functionMap.find(name);
 temp = itor->second;

 return temp;
}

std::map<std::string, std::function<Interface*(void)> > functionMap;

};
```

This is failing to compile because of the line:

```
  temp = itor->second;
```

The error describes failing to covert between `std::function<Interface*(void)>` and `Instance*`. How do I achieve this conversion (static, dynamic casts don't work)

As a follow up question to this does anyone have any ideas how to make this work for non empty constructors?

Comment: The second question makes no sense. Nothing in this code sample has anything to do with constructors.

Comment: Wait, I'm looking closer, is `Instance` supposed to be `Interface`? Does the compiler even allow the line `virtual void init =0;`?

Comment: That might of been me making a typo this is a simplified version of the actual implementation

Comment: Make sure you _run_ and _test_ the version that you post to us here.

Comment: I would have done although the machine i'm on at the moment doesn't have a compiler

Comment: @Nark http://ideone.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To call the function, you add the parenthesis:

```
temp = itor->second();
```

Comment: Man that was a stupid mistake, the second hand of this question still stands.

Comment: @Nark I think you should ask a new question. Currently, as I stated in the comments of the question, nothing in this sample has anything to do with constructors.